# Unsupported format character ";". Can't figure this out

Tags: python, html, string, format

I've been stumped on what is probably a very stupid mistake for a while now.  Searching google has not helped me.

I am learning python and trying to create a simple signup page.  When I try to use string substitution I seems to be failing with this error:
`Unsupported format character ";"`

This is the python code.

```
def write_form(self, username=""):
    self.response.out.write(signupform %{'usr': username})
```

Here is the html:

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Username:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="%(usr)s"><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html probably contains some other `%` character.

My wild guess is something like `style="width:100%; heigh:20px;"` somewhere.

You should double all raw `%` in the file to escape them.

Comment: Yep! Thanks very much, your wild guess was right.  I knew it would be something simple like that but I never even thought it might be the css.